# How to change the RadDataForm style in nativescript-vue ? (Nativescript-Vue)

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How to change font-size, border-color e.t.c styling of email and password present in the person object.

```
 <RadDataForm :source="person"</RadDataForm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-vue/blob/master/dataform/app/examples/EditorsStyle.ts) seems to be a perfect example you are looking, use `TKPropertyEditorStyle` to define custom font, size, color etc.,

```html
    <template>
        <Page class="page">
            <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
            <RadDataForm ref="dataForm" :source="person">
                <TKEntityProperty v-tkDataFormProperty name="name">
                    <TKPropertyEditor v-tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text">
                        <TKPropertyEditorStyle v-tkPropertyEditorStyle
                            labelTextColor="red"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
                    </TKPropertyEditor>
                </TKEntityProperty>
                <TKEntityProperty v-tkDataFormProperty name="age">
                    <TKPropertyEditor v-tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Decimal">
                        <TKPropertyEditorStyle v-tkPropertyEditorStyle
                            labelTextColor="green"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
                    </TKPropertyEditor>
                </TKEntityProperty>
                <TKEntityProperty v-tkDataFormProperty name="birthDate">
                    <TKPropertyEditor v-tkEntityPropertyEditor type="DatePicker">
                        <TKPropertyEditorStyle v-tkPropertyEditorStyle
                            labelTextColor="blue"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
                    </TKPropertyEditor>
                </TKEntityProperty>
            </RadDataForm>
        </Page>
    </template>

    <script>
        import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
        import RadDataForm from "nativescript-ui-dataform/vue";
        Vue.use(RadDataForm);

        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    person: {
                        name: "John",
                        age: 23,
                        birthDate: "1993-05-16"
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Using your code I am able to change input field Label style like color, font-size e.t.c But I want to change input field border-color when user tap on an input field.